# What is the way to migrate Sitecore media files stored in file system(App_data) to Azure Blob

Tags: sitecore-client

I want to move sitecore media files to azure blob storage. Sitecore migration scripts help to migrate media that is stored in a database only. Is there any way to move files that are stored in a file system? It has around 100 GB in size.

Comment: You are probably looking for this - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/531/convert-disk-based-media-to-database

Comment: No, this is to migrate media files from 'file system' to database. I am talking about Azure blob Storage

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to do a blob upload using C# code. Here is a code snippet you can try.

```
private void UploadToBlob (CustomArgs args) { 
    // Get your Azure Connection string you saved previously 
    string cn = Sitecore.Configuration.Settings.GetConnectionString(); 
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(cn); 
    PathMapper path = new PathMapper(); // Create a blob client for interacting with the blob service. 
    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient(); // Create a blob container 
    var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(BlobContainer); 
    blobContainer.CreateIfNotExists(); // Source from where to upload the files to the blob 
    var sourcePath = path.MapPath(args.SourceUrl); // Filename for the blob 
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(args.SourceUrl); 
    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName); 
    cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromFile(sourcePath);
    }
```

Reference: https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/08/01/sitecore-integration-with-azure-blob-storage/

Hope this helps.